# How to use the Controls and Forms of Visual Studio to access the TFS Version Control

Tags: .net, user-interface, version-control, tfs

With the Classes from the namespaces **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client** and **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client** it is possible to access the Team Foundation Server Version Control (TFS-VC) programatically.

Is it also possible to use the Controls and Forms that are used in Visual Studio in an own application? It looks like most of the classes in **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls** are marked as internal and therefore not available outside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, the following I used for TFS2010 and found it somehwere in the internet, it opens the SourceControlFileSelector:

```
                VersionControlServer versionControlServer = (VersionControlServer)tfsConnection.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
                Assembly controlsAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.ControlAddItemsExclude));

                Type vcChooseItemDialogType = controlsAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.DialogChooseItem");
                ConstructorInfo ci = vcChooseItemDialogType.GetConstructor(
                                   BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                   null,
                                   new Type[] { typeof(VersionControlServer) },
                                   null);
                _chooseItemDialog = (Form)ci.Invoke(new object[] { versionControlServer });
                _chooseItemDialog.ShowDialog();
                this.DialogResult = _chooseItemDialog.DialogResult;


                _selectItemProperty = vcChooseItemDialogType.GetProperty("SelectedItem", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                Item selectedItem = (Item)_selectItemProperty.GetValue(_chooseItemDialog, null);
```

For TFS2012 there are some dialogs directly usable, like the TeamProjectPicker:

```
        TeamProjectPicker dp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.NoProject, false);
        DialogResult dr = dp.ShowDialog();
        if (dr.Equals(DialogResult.OK) && dp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection != null)
        {
            Name = dp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection.ConfigurationServer.Name;
            configTfsUrl = dp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection.ConfigurationServer.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            tfsUrl = dp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection.Uri;
        }
```

Comment: So there is no 'official' way for TFS2010 that avoids using reflection?

Comment: Unfortunately I have never seen one. Even the reflection way I have only seen once.